# Binding doesn't update onPropertyChange

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a viewmodel, in which I regularly update one of my parameters from a bluetooth module. (I have a breakpoint in my setter, so I'm sure its being updated)

The parameters does correctly update in my viewmodel, and I'm sure that my binding is correct in my view.

I suspect that my `propertyChanged?` method is the one that bugs my code:

```
 public class Viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
      public Viewmodel()
      {
      }
      public string CurrentValue
      {
           get
           {
                return _currentValue;
             }
             set
             {
                  if (_currentValue!= value)
                  {
                       _currentValue= value;
                       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(CurrentValue));
                  }
             }
      }
}
```

View:

```
<Label Text="{Binding BindingContext.CurrentValue, Source={x:Reference Name=MyCarousel}}"/>
```

View CodeBehind:

```
public partial class View: ContentPage
{
    public TemperaturePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCarousel.BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Fyi, I'm using Xabre BLE to facilitate the connection, and my characteristic listener which updates my viewmodel looks as follows:

```
public async void GetValuesFromCharacteristic()
{
    Viewmodel viewModel = new Viewmodel();

    Characteristic.ValueUpdated += (s, a) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Characteristic.Value[7].ToString());

        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            viewModel.CurrentValue = Characteristic.Value[7].ToString();
        });
    };
    await Characteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
}
```

To me it seems, that `PropertyChanged?` remains null, thus why nothing is updated.

Comment: `new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentValue))` is the solution

Comment: so: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentValue)));` It doesn't really work. :-(

Comment: Can you provide a small sample?

Comment: By sample you mean?

Comment: You could try to put `Viewmodel viewModel = new Viewmodel();` outsite the `GetValuesFromCharacteristic` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [dymanoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770516/binding-doesnt-update-onpropertychange#comment101976231_57770516), the parameter to `PropertyChangedEventArgs` should be a `string` with the name of the property that changed.

The ViewModel also needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It does not in your example code, but I'm assuming that's just a sample definition for this question.

Comment: That doesn't work. I've made the changes that i posted as a comment above. Still no change at all.

Comment: There is buggy issue still not fixed i think.